# Pandas equivalent rbind operation

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, I am looping through a bunch of CSV files and in the end would like to `append` each dataframe into one. Actually, all I need is an `rbind` type function. So, I did some search and followed the [guide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). However, I still could not get the ideal solution.

A sample code is attached below. For instance shape of data1 is always 47 by 42. But shape of `data_out_final` becomes (47, 42), (47, 84), and (47, 126) after the first three files. Idealy, it should be (141, 42). In addition, I check index of `data1`, which is `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=47, step=1)`. Appreciate any suggestions!

My `pandas` version is `0.18.1`

### code

```
appended_data = []
for csv_each in csv_pool:
    data1 = pd.read_csv(csv_each, header=0)
    # do something here
    appended_data.append(data2) 
data_out_final = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=1)
```

If using `data_out_final = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=1)`, shape of data_out_final becomes (141, 94)

### PS

kind of figure it out. Actually, you have to standardize column names before `pd.concat`.

Comment: How would you describe your "ideal solution"?

Comment: @SO44, Idealy, it should be (141, 42) for `appending` three (47,42) df.

Comment: `axis=0` for adding rows (which is the default value of `axis` if not specified)

Comment: @M.Klugerford, I tried using `axis=0`, however, it is not the same...

Comment: @ayhan, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @tao.hong When you "do something", is it possible that you change the column names? Because if you have different column names pd.concat would introduce new columns.

Comment: @ayhan, Just figured that out! It is the column names. thanks!

Comment: Glad that it resolved. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> df1
          a         b
0 -1.417866 -0.828749
1  0.212349  0.791048
2 -0.451170  0.628584
3  0.612671 -0.995330
4  0.078460 -0.322976
5  1.244803  1.576373
6  1.169629 -1.135926
7 -0.652443  0.506388
8  0.549604 -0.691054
9 -0.512829 -0.959398

>>> df2
          a         b
0 -0.652161  0.940932
1  2.495067  0.004833
2 -2.187792  1.692402
3  1.900738  0.372425
4  0.245976  1.894527
5  0.627297  0.029331
6 -0.828628 -1.600014
7 -0.991835 -0.061202
8  0.543389  0.703457
9 -0.755059  1.239968

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2])
          a         b
0 -1.417866 -0.828749
1  0.212349  0.791048
2 -0.451170  0.628584
3  0.612671 -0.995330
4  0.078460 -0.322976
5  1.244803  1.576373
6  1.169629 -1.135926
7 -0.652443  0.506388
8  0.549604 -0.691054
9 -0.512829 -0.959398
0 -0.652161  0.940932
1  2.495067  0.004833
2 -2.187792  1.692402
3  1.900738  0.372425
4  0.245976  1.894527
5  0.627297  0.029331
6 -0.828628 -1.600014
7 -0.991835 -0.061202
8  0.543389  0.703457
9 -0.755059  1.239968
```

Unless I'm misinterpreting what you need, this is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Try: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html?highlight=concat#concat

"pandas provides various facilities for easily combining together Series, DataFrame, and Panel objects with various kinds of set logic for the indexes and relational algebra functionality in the case of join / merge-type operations."